# How to read MS word form fields using c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I tried to read the word document which includes text and form fields. I need to read all text and fields in the document. But the below code always return empty value. It never entering the foreach loop. I don't know what is the issue as there is no error while built. But I didn't get the output. I write it in c# .net 4.6.2 and it will be used as a library file. Is there anything wrong with the code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Activities;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace WordExer
{
  public class WordExer : CodeActivity
  {
    [Category("Input")]
    public InArgument<string> AVal { get; set; }

    [Category("Output")]
    public OutArgument<string> CVal { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        var a = AVal.Get(context);
        string text = "";
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Add(a);

        doc.Activate();

        foreach (FormField field in doc.FormFields)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(field.Range.Text);
            text += field.Range.Text;
        }
        CVal.Set(context, text);
        word.Quit();
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: you can try  foreach(InlineShape filed in doc.InlineShapes) ---> this loops through all the fields in your document

Comment: @ApoorvaRaju I think the shapes and form controls are different. I tried shapes. It worked for textbox but not for form input controls.

Comment: Are you certain these are *form fields* and not something else, such as content controls? If you Debug.Print doc.FormFields.Count, what's returned? If you're unsure what these Input fields are, what commands are used to insert them? Maybe provide a screen shot...

Comment: @ApoorvaRaju **InlineShapes** work but `field.Range.Text` return only **"CONTROL Forms.TextBox.1"**.   I want to get the value for each of it.

Comment: @Cindy FormFields.Count return nothing. Those fields are **ActiveX controls**.

Comment: @ranjith I would be posting some code part as answer you can try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to access them as inline shapes as depicted in below code snippet

```
 foreach (InlineShape shape in doc.InlineShapes)
 {
       if (shape.OLEFormat != null && shape.OLEFormat.ClassType == "CONTROL Forms.TextBox.1")
       {
              Console.WriteLine("Data :" + shape.OLEFormat.Object.Value);
       }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Apoorva. It works. I modified **if condition line** as `if (shape.OLEFormat != null && shape.OLEFormat.ClassType == "Forms.TextBox.1")`. I think the editing word document will be in the same way.

Comment: Welcome :) yes you can edit object.value that would edit the word file and later save it

Comment: Is there anyway to get value based on index? anything like this doc.InlineShapes[1].OLEFormat.Object.Value.